# Accidentally deleted page.xml. How do I get it back?

Tags: file, magento, layout, radix

I have accidentally deleted the file app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/page.xml from my directory.

My understanding is that this is the 'default' page.xml file that comes with Magento. How can I get this file back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the file from:
http://svn.magentocommerce.com/source/branches/1.7/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/page.xml

If you have an other version of Magento, you might want to tweak with the version in the URL.
You could also redownload Magento and search for the file in the package if this won't work out.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to just go over to [www.magentocommerce.com/download](http://www.magentocommerce.com/download), select the release archive tab, grab the .zip archive for the version you are working with and unzip it into a temp folder. You then have all the files that make up Magento right there stored in the exact same directory tree as exists on your website, very easy to retrieve.

Personally, I keep the archives on hand for the current version, previous version and next version in my upgrade path. That way I always have an easy reference if some code oddity comes up in my custom templates and modules.